# Word classes in specific sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

Consider the following setup. What would the word classes of "out" and "there" be?

> "Where is James?"
>
> "He is out there somewhere, right in the middle of the storm."

I was first thinking in the direction of "to be out there" being a phrasal verb, but I know that can't be true. This leaves me to think that `there` is a demonstrative pronoun (correct me if I'm wrong), but I can't figure out what the word class of "out" is in that case.

Comment: 'out there' acts like an adverb.

Comment: But shouldn't each word have a word class separately? Are they both adverbs then?

Comment: I think _out there_ is a set phrase.

Comment: *There* is routinely an adverb, while *out* is routinely used as an adverb, adjective, preposition, noun **and** verb. Think a bout it for a while.

Comment: No, each word does  ALWAYS not get its own word class. For example, there exist multiword prepositions. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions for examples of multiword preps.

Comment: @tchrist I pronounce [forby](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forby) not as /for 'baj/ but as /'for bij/, you know like a funny furby.

Comment: 'Out there' is a locative here (it would be directional in 'He went out there'). In the directional usage, it can be seen that the function is adverbial, modifying _go_. The snag is that with _be_, merely linking subject and location, the concept of verb modification does not apply (at least in the same way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words *out* and *there* are both prepositions. In this particular instance the preposition *out* is taking the preposition *there* as its complement. For a modern account of prepositions see one of the following vetted grammar sources:

- *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* Huddleston & Pullum, 2002
- *Oxford Modern English Grammar* Aarts, 2011

Whereas before the great linguist Otto Jespersen, people had identified prepositions as a family of words that occurred before nouns, Jespersen had the insight to observe that this family was being misidentified, or rather misdescribed. He noted that words such as *in, on, at, after, before, until* have the same syntactic properties regardless of whether they occurred before nouns or not. In a blinding flash of what can surely only be described as common sense, he decided that these were actually always the same words. This radical idea follows on rather mundanely, but methodically, from the way that we treat other parts of speech such as nouns or verbs.

Modern grammars such as CaGEL have gone one step further than this, but this need not bother us here. One knock-on effect of realising that prepositions need not always precede nouns, is that some prepositions don't occur before nouns at all, in the same way that some verbs never take objects. Such words include items such as:

- abroad, here, there, away, back, out

Prepositions such as *out* and *there* have various syntactic properties in common with other prepositons:

- they are modifiable by the specialised adverbs *straight* and *right*.
- they occur as the complements of other prepositions.
- they occur as complements of the verb *BE*.
- they, and the phrases they head, can post-modify nouns.
- they aren't modifiable by *very*.

Notice that *out there* is a complement of *BE* in the OP's example. We could also have :

- He was *right* out there, in the middle of the storm.

The preposition phrase could be used to post-modify a noun:

- The man right out there in the middle of the storm.

The whole phrase could be the complement of another preposition:

- He went back out there.

All of this shows *out there* to be a preposition phrase. Notice that none of the tests above will work with adverbs. You can test this yourself with an adverb like *locally*, for example.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Not sure all those tests really work equally well. “That's very out there” sounds fine to me, as does “It happened right locally”; and in “that one there”, _there_ surely post-modifies the head noun, doesn't it? Treating _there_ as a preposition also entails a nomenclature that borders on the absurd, in that _there_ **cannot** take an object and thus cannot be preposited at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *It happened right locally* might sound ok to you if you're from Yorkshire as might, *she's right hot*, but it's not standard in SSBE that's for sure. And, yes, *very out there* is idiomatic, but *she went very out* aint (as I'm sure you'll agree). Neither is *Put it very there* or *she's very in the bath*. Of course there's idiomatic compounds that are a bit different, but the generalisations hold true. I can't bothered  to go and put *freely* and *usually* everywhere today! "*That one there*", if it does post-modify the noun  surely backs up the point that prepositions ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... er, post-modify nouns! Yes, the absolute unforgibvable idiocy that identified a group of words according to the complements they take, left grammarians like H&P in a quandry. Their thinking is, it's just too widely used to change. They point out that there's loads of other idiot names out there like *adverb* and *adjective*, for words that describe words other than adverbs and aren't necessarily adjacent to nouns! I'd change the name -  but it's not up to me. One thing's for sure, just because they've got a silly name doesn't mean we should be silly just to be consistent!

Comment: Oh! I read that that as “they and the phrases they modify _can’t_ post-modify nouns” and didn’t think. Duh. I don’t know, I just still feel like this whole Pullum-inspired fad of lumping more or less everything that doesn’t end in _-ly_ in as a preposition is a smoke screen. Might as well stick to calling them adverbs and have that be the messy free-for-all category, ’cause that’s what prepositions are becoming to me. Does CGEL actually categorise _where?_ as a preposition, or was that just somewhere else I saw Pullum talk about that?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, they do p.614-5!

Answer (score -1):

Out there would be predicate adjective modifying He.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please support your answer with sources. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise, even if it's correct, it's only opinion. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site.